# How to find an android instant app in google play store or on web?

Tags: android, android-developer-api, android-instant-apps

I am searching for an instant app. Please suggest me an app which i can review to study regarding instant app also if possible please suggest a good tutorial as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can check this FragmentedPodcast Episode talking about Instant Apps [Fragmented Podcast Episode 90](http://fragmentedpodcast.com/episodes/90/) also find more about it in the show notes.

Here are the [Google Samples Repository](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-instant-apps) for Instant Apps.

Answer (score 1):

This article gives you an overview on how to prepare your existing app to support AIA feature (how to reduce the size of your app, what are the restricted and unsupported features, what libraries are compatible with AIA, etc.):

https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/prepare.html

For steps on how to convert your non-AIA project into one that includes the instant app check out these:

- list of steps for conversion -
  https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/getting-started/index.html
- great practice tutorial -
  https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-instant-apps/index.html#0
- example with Jet app -
  https://medium.com/jet-stories/make-your-app-instant-33855ab5d02b

And as hsm59 mentioned, there are also helpful Google sample apps for reference:  https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/samples.html

You can test some existing instant apps with these example URLs by opening the link via Gmail, Hangouts, etc:

- https://www.yummly.com/recipes
- https://www.skyscanner.net/flights-from/lond/cheap-flights-from-london.html
- https://www.buzzfeed.com/tasty

Or you can search for “buzzfeed tasty” in your browser, and you’ll see a “Buzzfeed app - instant" in the search results, this link will launch the Buzzfeed instant app.